# How to solve "Access Violation" when using iterators?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a class named `CLine`, which contains `vector<CPoint>`. I saved all the points along the line in the `vector<CPoint> m_vecPoint`. I was trying to traverse the points when the problem occurs.

My code:

```
for(vector<CLine>::iterator iter = m_vecLine.begin(); iter != m_vecLine.end(); iter++)
{
    vector<CPoint>::iterator iter1 = iter->m_vecPoint.begin();
    int temp = iter1->x;
}
```

When I debug this, it downs at `int temp = iter1->x` saying `Access Violation`.

What may be wrong?

Comment: Maybe `m_vecPoint` is empty?

Comment: have you tried dereferencing the iterator?

Comment: I tried again and detected that m_vecPoint is empty,thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be possible that **begin == end**

```
for(vector<CLine>::iterator iter = m_vecLine.begin(); iter != m_vecLine.end(); iter++)
{
    vector<CPoint>::iterator iter1 = iter->m_vecPoint.begin();
    if(iter1 != iter->m_vecPoint.end())
    { int temp = iter1->x;}
}
```

Comment: m_vecPoint is empty,thanks!

Comment: ok your welcome but close/check my answer...:)

Comment: I clicked on the "tick",is it?